# If a button is created inside a function, where is the right place to add it, so it is accessible?

Tags: ios, swift

```
func createButton() {
    let b = UIButton()
    // Some code to modify image of button
    b.addTarget(self, action: "fade", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
    self.view.addSubview(b)
    // Some code to add constraints    
}

func fade() {
    UIView.animeWithDuration(5, animations: {
        self.b.alpha = 0 // Error (ViewController has no member 'b')
}
```

Do I get this error because, `createButton()` has a separate view from `ViewController`? Because I have tried passing in the button, and using `sender.view.b.alpha = 0`, but `UIButton` has no `view`.

Thank you.

Comment: Hmm yes that is what I though. And you are referring to the button correct? Can I not pass it into the function?

Comment: Ok I realized that when I passed in the button earlier, I used an incorrect reference. I should've used `func fade(sender: UIButton)` and `sender.alpha = 0`. But it leads to another error. But so long as I'm doing this correctly, this part of the problem is fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the button in the right scope. Currently you´re only declaring it in the function scope of createButton. But you could make it an instance variable of your class. Then you can access it from both methods.

```
class XYZ
{

     var button: UIButton?

     func createButton() {
        self.button = UIButton()
        // Some code to modify image of button
        self.button.addTarget(self, action: "fade", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
        self.view.addSubview(self.button)
        // Some code to add constraints    
     }

     func fade() {
          UIView.animeWithDuration(5, animations: {
                self.button.alpha = 0
     }
}
```

Also [here](https://andybargh.com/lifetime-scope-and-namespaces-in-swift/) is an article about scopes and lifetime of objects in Swift.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I actually wanted to create a button (with a varying name) every time the function is called. This is possible right?

Comment: @fossdeep That's what Philipp's answer does. It *declares* an Optional button at the root of the class, then it *creates* a button in the func and assigns the button to the declared variable.

Comment: Ah I see. It makes sense now. Thank you.